# How can the probability of a needle landings inside a grid tiled by equilateral triangles be calculated?

Tags: probability, integration, geometry

I am looking into variations of Buffon's Needle problem and after working out Laplace's extension, I wanted to look at how a probability can be derived for a triangular grid. The question proposed would be: Given a needle of length $l$, what is the probability that it intersects at least 1 line on a grid tiled by equilateral triangles with altitude $d$. (Assume that $l \le d$)

Similarly to Laplace's case, I have calculated the area in which the midpoint of the needle can land without intersecting a line.

I reason that this area is a smaller equilateral triangle. I should then integrate over possible values of the angle that the needle makes with the x axis and divide this by the volume of all possibilities.

In theory, taking the complement of this would yield the desired answer.

Is this the correct approach? It would be even better if there are some values which I can compare my working out to. Thanks!

Comment: https://hal.science/hal-03611482v1/file/Pages%20de%20%282011-2014%29-31.pdf